# visualizing a large table in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, data.table, fread

Working in R, I have a CSV file that looks like this(the first value is blank)...

```
NA,V1,x

1,1,0.999796678947516
2,2,0.999346571923341
3,3,0.999456172849271
...
```

The file is 7537423 rows, about 264 MB.

I have been trying to visualize this table, without success.  I want to start as simple as possible, and visualize with V1 as time and x as itself(like an X,Y graph?)

the code I have tried most recently...

```
library(tabplot)
library(data.table)   
library(ggplot2)

stuff <- fread("tradeOffsBETA.csv")

tableplot(stuff, select = c("V1","x"), sortCol = "V1")
```

which gives the following output

```
Read 7537423 rows and 3 (of 3) columns from 0.264 GB file in 00:00:50
Error in ff(initdata = initdata, length = length, 
levels = levels, ordered = ordered,  :  vmode 'character' not implemented
```

thanks for any help

Comment: Try setting `colClasses ='numeric'` in the `fread` call. Looks like the blank line is making the columns character class.

Comment: Are the headers included in the file? If so, you don't need to worry about the first column. R will automatically figure out that it is an index. If the headers are in the file, read it like this: stuff <- read.csv("tradeOffsBETA.csv",header=TRUE,colClasses=c('numeric','numeric'))

Comment: @BondedDust ran tableplot(stuff, select = c("V1","x"), sortCol = "V1",colClasses ='numeric') and got the same error

Comment: @Michal the headers are in fact in the file.  I will try your suggestion in a bit, though from what I understand, read.csv is much slower than fread

Comment: @Michal I tried with read.csv as suggested and got error 'Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  scan() expected 'a real', got '"1"'' 

replaced read.csv(suggested parameters) with fread(suggested parameters) and got error 'Error in fread("tradeOffsBETA.csv", header = TRUE, colClasses = c("numeric",  : 
  colClasses is unnamed and length 2 but there are 3 columns. See ?data.table for colClasses usage.'

ran with colClasses=c('numeric','numeric','numeric') 3 columns as in the file, and got the original error

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Before  running tableplot, make sure the columns of your data frame are Factors and not Characters.

```
stuff <- as.data.frame(sapply(stuff,function(col){
      if(class(col)=="character"){
        col <- as.factor(col)
      }
      col
    })
    )
```